# String literal pattern

Tags: typescript, redux

I've seen some examples with TypeScript and Redux where the following [pattern](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter#adding-actions) is used to declare an action type string:

```
export const CREATE_TASK = 'CREATE_TASK';
export type CREATE_TASK = typeof CREATE_TASK;
```

I kind of understand that the second line is called a type alias, and it forces a variable of that type - named CREATE_TASK to contain the string literal 'CREATE_TASK'. I suspect this is equivalent to the "string literal types" mentioned in this article: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Is this true? Could some one give me an explanation of line 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things at work here, the definition of a type and the definition of a variable value.

The first line defines a variable `CREATE_TASK` with the value `'CREATE_TASK'`. Pretty straight forward.

The second line defines a type called `CREATE_TASK` which happens to have the type of the `CREATE_TASK` variable which happens to be a string `'CREATE_TASK'`.  It is the equivalent of defining like so:

```
export type CREATE_TASK = 'CREATE_TASK';
```

Except you don't have to enter the string again, just use the existing variable to derive the type.

The idea here is to create a constant enumeration that is strongly typed. This helps pattern matching for discriminated unions work more effectively by allowing these constants be used as the discriminants.  You can restrict what constants are allowable and have compiler support to let you know that you cover all the necessary cases.